# Django Media File deployment - change in file location

Tags: django, amazon-s3, storage, digital-ocean

I am having a web server running in Digitalocean. We are in a situation where we need to upload our clients' images (media files). Now, as far as the understating goes, in the following case:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    photo = models.ImageField(storage=fs)
```

The photo field will store the url of the file, right?

Now we might move to amazon (with S3 as the storage system) in near future. Will the model field value change?

How do you, then, suggest us in taking care of the change (as we will have two servers then, one EC2 for django & S3 for media & static files)?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your static and media files to S3 during deployment after `collectstatic`. In case of multiple servers, you only need to run `collectstatic` in one server, then you will be able to reach same content from S3 for multiple servers.

If you take a look https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/ there is  a detailed guide on how to store files on S3.

Comment: Hey @hybor thanks a lot for your reply. While I had some idea of serving static files via S3, you have indeed helped. Thanks. But my primary doubt is this: currently my static files and django project is served from the same server. Once I change it, will it affect the model field? (As said in the question?). Thanks

Comment: No it will not effect the model field. storage=fs will store your files under /media/photos folder (I personally use upload_to='model_name/images' option in my ImageFields). collectstatic and sending S3 will handle your case also.